# Close form not showing in application openforms

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, user32

I use the below code to pop-up a form on the screen on top of everything but it doesn't steal focus.

This works fine, but I now need to close the form, the form itself doesnt show up in `Application.OpenForms`

How do I go about doing this?

Setup and open the form

```
frmClientCall frm = new frmClientCall {StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual, Text = "Phone Call"};
frm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - frm.Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - frm.Height - 202
);
frm.lblClient.Text = URI;
frm.ShowInactiveTopmost();
```

Code to prevent focus on the form

```
private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(
     int hWnd,             // Window handle
     int hWndInsertAfter,  // Placement-order handle
     int X,                // Horizontal position
     int Y,                // Vertical position
     int cx,               // Width
     int cy,               // Height
     uint uFlags);         // Window positioning flags

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

public void ShowInactiveTopmost()
{
    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
    SetWindowPos(Handle.ToInt32(), HWND_TOPMOST, Left, Top, Width, Height, SWP_NOACTIVATE);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is not the only mishap.  You for example can also see that the form's Load event never fires.  Basic issue is that you are bypassing the normal logic, which is a pretty big deal in Winforms since it creates the native window lazily.  In your case it happens when you use the Handle property.  I *think* the underlying issue is that the Visible property was never set to *true*, that's the one that truly gets the ball rolling.

Well, don't do it this way, Winforms already supports showing a window without activating it.  Paste this code into the form you want to display without activation:

```
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation {
        get { return true; }
    }
```

The SetWindowPos() pinvoke to make it topmost is not necessary either, paste this code:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 8;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOPMOST
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the test form appears to have worked, just need to test the toast form with the phone system implementation to make sure the form closes on the event firing and then I'll mark as correct answer!